# WP WordPress theme issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a free WP theme but know next to nothing about PHP. I don't know what to put around this code and would greatly appreciate if somebody could put the correct PHP tags around it, as telling me what to put is a bit like speaking Latin to me.  I tried putting `<?php` at the beginning and `?>` at the end but it didn't work:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' ) {
  //  aside format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('gallery')) {
   // stuff to display the gallery format post here
} else if (has_post_format('link')) {
   // link format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('video')) {
   // video format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('audio')) {
   // audio format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('status')) {
   // status format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('chat')) {
   // chat format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('quote')) {
   // quote format post content here
} else if (has_post_format('image')) {
   // image format post content here
}else {
   // code to display the normal format post here
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: "a great free WP theme....know nothing about PHP" classic  +1

Comment: @dqhendricks it returns the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'

@sdolgy - Some of us do the graphic design end of things, and the theme has been community built for the most part, now I'm adding some finishing touches.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: see also the switch control structure ( http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `<?php` in front of every line that does not hold any code (thus starts with if or }),
and end those lines with `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this first line is wrongs.

```
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' ) {
```

should be

```
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' ) ) {
```